# Installed Ubuntu, windows 7 boots up by default?

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04

I have windows 7 installed in my C:\ partition .Now I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my D:\ partition ,but I don't know how to boot to Ubuntu.... ? Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

If you installed grub onto your 'c:' drive (primary boot device), then hit shift when turning it on to bring up the menu. If you are using the windows 7 bootloader, hit f8 to bring up the windows boot menu.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't install Grub in any of my partitions or hard disk , if I press f8 after the windows boot menu ,will I be asked to choose between these 2 OS (win7 and Ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set two different partitions inside windows itself and assigned driver letters to both of them then they will act as two different drives, the best option for dual booting windows 7 and Ubuntu is to remove the ubuntu partition, reallocate it back to your windows 7 partition, reboot machine boot into the Ubuntu live cd and set the partitions in the installation software.

If you do it that way then you will be given the option automatically to choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Will I be able to access the partition without formatting it ? (as I have some photos I forgot to delete in that partiton ...)

Comment: On your Windows or Ubuntu Partition ? 

if you are have them saved on your Ubuntu Partition boot into windows you will be able to gain access the the files by going into the drive your ubuntu installation is on then head to

Home > (your username for ubuntu) > then where ever you have saved the pictures.  then all you have to do is copy and paste them into a folder on your windows installation.  Once you have done all of that then remove your Ubuntu installation, delete the partition, reallocate it to the Windows partition the boot from Ubuntu Live cd

Comment: No other partition beside the C:\ partition is not showing up, althought I'm 100% sure I installed ubuntu on my D:\ partition ,that partition is not showing up ... !

Comment: Have you tried looking into your My Computer? 
if its not showing there then try looking in your partition software, if it is not showing up there then it may seem as if the partition has been deleted.  Normally what happens when you set a partition and assign it a drive letter in Windows is that it will show up in My Computer.